# How to merge several predictions into a single decision

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Disclaimer**: I am *not* actually trying to predict the football match outcomes and I am *not* betting. Football is only taken for illustration.

Given there are several different independent predictors that predict  outcome of the same binary event, each with its own confidence defined by the probability of their terminal probability variable taking the given value.

What are the common ways, or how would you merge those recommendations into a single decision outcome or a single variable probability that predicts the outcome more accurately than each of the predictors individually?

To illustrate my question, here is an example.

- Predictor A predicts the win of the team *t* in a football match *m* with probability 0.6.
- Predictor B predicts the win of the team *t* in a football match *m* with probability 0.55.
- Predictor C predicts the win of the team *t* in a football match *m* with probability 0.71.

How would you merge those inputs into a single probability of an event outcome (team *t* winning the match *m*) to base your decision for whether to place a bet or not in order to obtain better probability of overall prediction success?

***Additional Context***

To help community readers with intentional ambiguities in the question and in an attempt to qualify as a valid question for the Mathematics StackExchange, here are some of my "thoughts" even though I'd really like to ask you for your suggestions on this topic.

I call "predictor" a process that calculates a probability of a given probability variable taking a given value, e.g. on the picture:

P<sub>A</sub>(E=e|A,B=b,C,...)

P<sub>B</sub>(E=e|D=d,F,G=g,...)

P<sub>C</sub>(E=e|H,I=i,J,...)

I am looking at possible strategies of making a decision based on the given input.

P(E=e|E<sub>A</sub>,E<sub>B</sub>,E<sub>C</sub>)

What is the additional information that I need to know about predictors A, B, C in order to improve the probability of successful overall prediction?

I am sure that the merging of multiple independent probability predictions for the same event is a very common situation in practice in sophisticated systems. How are they dealing with this situation?

My current "straightforward" guess would be to measure the a-posteriori probability of each of the predictors e.g. basing on historical data to determine how often their prediction P(E) matches the real event outcomes and use that as the weight during "merging", e.g. as weighted average.

Will that improve the quality of the eventual prediction?

Is that how the tasks of this class are being solved in practice (e.g. gaming, health, other ML domains)?

Where can I read about this in greater detail?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thank you Jose, I appreciate your feedback especially in comparison to silent downvotes.
Before I delete my question, may I please ask what are additional details that are missing that you think are preventing providing thoughts input and help in this particular question?
This is a high level theoretical question, I don't expect exact mathematical answer.

Comment: Actually, you only got **one** downvote. And I think that you ought to show us what is it that you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: My score jumped +/- 10 several times immediately after I published my question. That made me thinking that there is more than 1 downvote (I obviously don't have enough score to see exact split though).
I'll add some simple thoughts on the topic that I have in a moment, though I don't think that in this context it would improve the question significatly.

Comment: The main problem of the question is that we have no idea how reliable the guesses are. A naive approach would be to simply take the arithmetic mean, but I do not think this will usually perform well.

Comment: Thank you @Peter, the question is ambiguous on purpose. I don’t have more fixed input than those listed in the question. I would be interested in knowing what additional input would be necessary to improve overall prediction performance.

Comment: To help with ambiguities I’ll add more considerations to the questions later today.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Added some more details to the question.
For a newcomer as me, the number of downvoted questions on MSE is significantly higher than in other communities.
I really think that my original question would have been valid in other SE communities that don't require submitting a tentative answer together with the question.
I also think that my question has nothing to do with http://goo.gl/mLWc8 that you've quoted and doesn't break any community policies.
As feedback, I'd recommend reviewing community criteria for new questions not to discourage newcomers.

Comment: For your future interest, you might look into ensemble learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Weighting" the probabilities of different pundits requires you to understand *[mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information)*. I'll just give some simple illustrative examples of mutual information and a reference in this answer.

Suppose we have probability of winning $P(W)$, and some pundits who try to guess the outcome. I'll calculate the mutual information between their guesses and the outcomes.

Pundit A (Mr Average) predicts completely at random, by throwing a coin. Because the probability of a win and the probability of Mr Average predicting a win are independent, $p(w,a)=p(w)p(a)$, where $a$ is the guess of Mr Average, the mutual information $I(W,A)$ between Mr Average and the actual outcome is given by
$$
I(W,A)=\sum_{w,a} p(w,a)\log_2{p(w,a)\over p(w)p(a)}\\
=\sum_{w,a} p(w,a)\log_2(1)\\
=0.\\
$$

Pundit C (Mr Clever) will predict completely accurately the outcome of any event. The "mutual information" $I(W,C)$ between Mr Clever and the actual outcome is
$$
I(W,C)=\sum_{w,c} p(w,c)\log_2{p(w,c)\over p(w)p(c)}\\
=\sum_{w} p(w)\log_2(p(w))\\
=1
$$
since $p(w|c)=1$ and $p(\bar{w}|\bar{c})=1$, where $\bar{w}$ indicates a loss.

Pundit B (Mr Better-than-average) predicts with an outcome of 0.75 of being right, and his mutual information
$$
I(W,B)=\sum_{w,b} p(w,b)\log_2{p(w,b)\over p(w)p(b)}\\
=-\sum_{w}p(w)\log_2(p(w))+\sum p(w,b)\log_2{p(w|b)}\\
=1+2\times0.5\times(0.25\log_2(0.25)+0.75\log_2(0.75))\\
\approx 0.2.
$$
Incidentally, pundit D (Mr Doofus) predicts worse than average with a 0.25 chance of being right, and his mutual information is exactly the same,
$$
I(W,D)\approx 0.2,
$$
since if Mr Doofus guesses a win, we bet on a lose, and vice-versa.

There is a more extensive discussion of the relation between mutual information and betting on sports outcomes in Cover and Thomas's book "Elements of Information Theory", chapter 6.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a weighted average of the probabilities might work. Give A, B, C weights $w_1$, $w_2$, $w_3$, (positive numbers ) and then say the probability of a win is

$$\frac{1}{w_1 + w_2 + w_3} (w_1 \cdot .6 + w_2 \cdot .55 + w_3 \cdot .71)$$

Now, $w_1$, $w_2$, $w_3$ would be determined from some other data. Say the more we trust  $A$, the bigger would be $w_1$ compared to the other $w_i$. Just an idea...

Comment: Thank you very much @orangeskid, greatly appreciated! 
I've added some of my considerations to the questions that go along with your hint as well. Is there anything more formal about the process of selecting the weights and some kind of a proof that such weighted approach will lead to the more accurate probability distribution than any of the individual predictors?
Are there any other possible approaches?

Comment: @Sergey Shcherbakov: You are very welcome!   I am aware of the Kalman filter, which does estimates with "changing weights".     Another one would be Viterbi decoding.  I'll try to think of other topics.

Comment: This won't work since you need to subtract away whatever part of the guesses that you can get by guessing at random. Also, if someone is a perfect predictor of the outcome (an "oracle"), how does that fit into this model?

Comment: Another issue with this is if pundit A always agrees with pundit B, so that pundit A's predictions don't add any more information than is found in pundit B's.

Comment: @Suzu Hirose: I see, good point about "repeaters".  Now, about the implementation, if we had a more "concrete"problem perhaps we could even implement a "strategy".  In any case, all these are models, and if the problem comes from "reality", testing will tell how well the implementation works.  Your points are very good!

Comment: Thank you for your considerations very much.
Even a better example for my situation is probably the typical probability theory example: a cancer test example (https://plus.maths.org/content/maths-minute-bayes-theorem). Imagine there are 3 such tests from different manufacturers with their own confusion matrix and F1 score. What is the way to improve cancer prediction results employing 3 different tests instead of 1?